# DataTables Select filter with fixed column

Tags: datatables, fixed

So, I have a DataTable with left fixed column but wanted to add a Select like filter, which is not supported by datatables.

I created the select filter and it works just fine withouth the fixed column as it filters from the original table. The thing is when I fix the left column, it doesn't apply the filter into the cloned table

I've tried adding and 'id' into the cloned table and then applying the filter into it too, but it won't work

As it is seen in the picture, the filter 'Externas' it's applied and should only show the orange rows, but the fixed columns shows every row

[Fixed column not filtering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhngr.png)

This is my select

```
<select id="filtrarTipo" onclick="filtradoTipo(); filtradoTipoC();">
 <option value="" selected disabled>Seleccione</option>
 <option value="">Todas</option>
 <option value="Interna">Interna</option>
 <option value="Externa">Externa</option>
</select>
```

And my jquery

```
function filtradoTipo() {
    // Declare variables
    var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById("filtrarTipo");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    table = document.getElementById("dtBecas");
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");


    // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
      td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[4];
      if (td) {
        txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
          tr[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
          tr[i].style.display = "none";
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: When you use the DataTables "fixed column" functionality, DataTables creates 2 separate HTML tables behind the scenes  and it layers one table over the other. So, the first problem is that your code is not searching across all columns - it is only searching in one of the tables.

Comment: The second problem is that searching in the DOM is not the right approach. You need to use the DataTables API and search directly in the DataTable JS object, instead (otherwise you will only be searching in the current page of results). You can see the general approach [in this example](https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html). But you will need to modify this, so you only have one select element, which searches all columns.